# How can visualize 5 channel of image one by one?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib

I have a numpy array which dimension is `(5, 3024, 4032)` and data type `float64`. It is a 5 channel image and my question is: how can I visualize each channel one by one?

My input:

```
data_gt = np.load('220200803_174029.npy')
data_gt.shape
# (5, 3024, 4032)


data_gt.dtype
# dtype('float64')
```

Comment: what do you mean with "visualize"? Graphically?

Comment: yes, graphically show all channel one by one.

Comment: what is the range of the pixels? 0-1? 0-255? or other?

Comment: It's sometimes neat to apprnd your 5 images side-by-side across the screen and view simultaneously. You can use `np.hstack((CHANNEL0,CHANNEL1...CHANNEL4))` to try it.

Comment: Does this work for you ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500637/how-to-extract-r-g-b-values-with-numpy-into-seperate-arrays

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_gt = np.load('220200803_174029.npy') 
for i, channel in enumerate(data_gt):
   plt.title("channel %i"%(i+1))
   plt.imshow(channel, cmap="Greys", vmin=data_gt.min(), vmax=data_gt.max())
   plt.show()
```

Comment: No, it's not working as it has an error which is 'ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False'.

Comment: @AsifuzzamanJishan I used you input. You have not specified `220200803_174029.npy` was a pickle file... Try using `allaw_pickle=True`, as the error suggests.